# what is Java Script hidden classes and how does it actually work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, v8

For every object we create in javascript the javascript engine creates a hidden class for it.Which contains properties and poperty attributes. llike offset,enumerable,writable etc.
My question is why does javascript use hidden classes.

`var x=new obj(2);//Assume we create a new obj with a proerty a initialized with 2;`
so var x contains the reference address of the object and we can access the property by adding required offset to the reference address. So why do we need hidden class?

Comment: That is an implementation detail of the V8 engine and there's quite a few articles available for free online explaining the purpose of this technique

Comment: Here's one such article: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a "hidden Javascript class" as there's no way to access the Javascript class directly.  This is just an internal detail of how V8 attempts to make accessing properties on a Javascript object as fast as possible.  It is not something that you would directly use in your Javascript programming.

Comment: Here is another article can be helpful : https://medium.com/swlh/writing-optimized-code-in-js-by-understanding-hidden-classes-3dd42862ad1d

Comment: thanks a lot ... this reource is also awesome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrufJFBSoQY